# Distribution of angle between two dependent gaussian random vectors

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation, angle

Suppose that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ have i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries. For some scalars $\alpha,\beta \in [-1,1]$, I am interested in the distribution of the angle $\theta$ between $x$ and $\alpha x + \beta y$. With the dependence between $x$ and $\alpha x + \beta y$, I am unsure how to go about this. Ultimately, I would like to compute something of the form $\mathbb{E}[g(\theta)]$ where $g$ is a continuous function. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes sorry I’ll fix that typo!

Comment: What is $g$ here?  That may simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: $g(\theta) = |\sin(\theta)| + \sin^{-1}(\cos(\theta))\cos(\theta)$

Comment: The cosine of the angle is $\dfrac{x\cdot(\alpha x + \beta y)}{\|x\|\|(\alpha x + \beta y\|}.$ One simple thing here is $\|x\| \sim \chi^2_n.$ At this point I'm wondering if an F-distribution or some variant of it is involved.

Comment: I forgot a superscript. $\qquad \uparrow \qquad \|x\|^2 \sim \chi^2_n. \qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy do you have any ideas for tackling the expected cosine?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mess and results are too long to reproduce here.

See Case III in *Distribution of the Phase Angle Between Two Vectors Perturbed by Gaussian Noise* by  Pawula, Rice and Roberts at:
 http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1095662

In your problem both vectors are $\vec{0}$ and the noise is correlated.

Comment: This article is incredibly hard to read. I'm not even sure if they tackle the expectation, rather than just the probability of being in some interval?

Comment: Yep, looks like it. They could examine $E[X] = \int_0^\infty [1-\int_0^x F(t)dt] dx$ which is also difficult.